# CSS to display two columns same height - depending on content added.

Tags: css, styles, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

I am using bootstrap columns, and want the two columns col-md-4 and col-md-8 to be the same height no matter the content. As col-md-4 content will change.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="col-md-4"></div>
 <div class="col-md-8"></div>
</div>
```

A google maps is the only thing in the col-md-8 and the div id map within has the height of 600px.

Comment: In BS 4 columns are the same height, but they should always be contained directly inside a `row`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `max-height` and it will not exceed that height. Since your map is 600px in height, you can set your `col-md-4` to that height, and let the content `overflow`.

I made a [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Hjorth/pen/jxybve)

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes that worked, I just had to change overflow to scroll - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: flex` to the container `col-md-12`.